# Understanding a Proof in Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

The following is an extract from my Galois Theory course lecture notes.

I understand the proof in the reverse direction so have included only the part of the proof that confuses me, even though it looks pretty harmless.

Can someone please explain why it is the case that $j(m_\alpha)(j(\alpha))=j(m_\alpha(\alpha))$ (*second line of proof*)? I can't see why this holds necessarily.

Everything else I follow. Thanks!

> > [image: Galois Theory Proof]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation "$j(m_\alpha)$" just means "apply $j$ to every coefficient of $m_\alpha$", and  $j(m_\alpha(\alpha))$ means "apply $j$ to the whole expression $m_\alpha(\alpha)$".  But $j$ is a homomorphism, so this is the same as applying $j$ to the coefficients and the powers of $\alpha$ separately.

Comment: Thanks, I (somehow) forgot that **very** important property of homomorphisms!